# Caching json response from server and automatically detect when the data is changed

Tags: json, angularjs, caching, local-storage, cachefactory

I am working on an angular app , which makes calls to a server and gets JSON data. I am looking at caching this JSON data.

Approach tried :

1) I tried using the html5 localSorage , to save the data locally. But , the problem with this is , i should manually set an expiration time and there is no way of knowing how occasionally the data will change.

2) I have tried using the $cacheFactory , however this does not cache data across refreshes or page navigations.

Solution I am looking for ,

I want the data to be saved locally or cached. And use some mechanism to detect if the data returned by the server has changed (JSON data) and only then make a call.

Is this possible in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your getting the data from html, calling the web service  and store the data in local storage.
In `$http`  success call the function which stores the data in local storage .

```
setUserDetails = function(userData){
var username = "";
if(userData != null){
app.setInLocalStorage("loginName",userData.userName);}
}
```

where userData is like a object holds the your html data,

```
var userData= {
 userName : $scope.userName,
 };
```

Get the `userData.userName` from local storage

```
 var userLoggedIn = app.retrieveFromLocalStorage("userName");
```

compare the data is it changed the from server or not

```
if(userLoggedIn != null){
            //call the service which gives dynamic response 
            //i hope your saving the success data in userData and userName is property which changes dynamically 
         var newUser = userData.userName;
        if(angular.equals(userLoggedIn, newUser){
             // maintain the same data in localstorage 
                        //or
               //No need to call any other function calls
         }else{    
                  //clear the old data from local storage 
                      app.clearLocalStorage();
                 //storage the new dynamic data in local storage 
                           //or
                  //call the new function calls if you need 
                app.setInLocalStorage("loginName",newUser)
             }
}
```

In app.js file include the following lines to storage ,retrieve,clear the local storage

```
setInLocalStorage : function(key , value) {
            // Check browser support
            if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined")
            {
                // Store
                localStorage.setItem(key , value);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
            }
        },
       retrieveFromLocalStorage : function(key){
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    },

    clearLocalStorage : function(){
        localStorage.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Hi , i have mentioned that , i did try using localStorage. You have assumed that if a new user logs in then i should change the data stored. However , thats not true , the data i am getting is common accross users and when changed , changes to all the users.